# MDX filter to disable writeback for passed time periods

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have a working SSAS writeback solution used for forecasting. There is only one measure [Value] and a few dimensions - two of which I would like to use to define writeback security.
The logic is that for each ForecastPeriod (like January, February etc) only "future dates" should be allowed writeback. Example: When creating the March forecast only March->December should be allowed input as January and February have passed.
In the dimension ForecastPeriod I have the data column ForecastFirstDate (for March it is (3/1/2018). My Date dimension has a Data Column MonthDate that holds the first date for each month.

Under the Cell Data tab when defining a new Role in BIDS I'm thinking I should have a MDX like this (and here is where I need help):
Date.MonthDate.CurrentMember >= ForecastPeriod.ForecastFirstMonthDate.CurrentMember

All help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That approach looks exactly correct. However there is one important nuance about implementing read-only security in one role and writeback security in a separate role. Please see more of an explanation [here](http://www.artisconsulting.com/blogs/greggalloway/2012/1/10/excel-writeback-security-and-leveraging-the-updateable-cell-property).